# If $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots$ are uniformly $\mathbb{P}$-integrable i.i.d. random variables, can $X_{n}\mathbb{I}(X_{1} > M)$ be made small?

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots$ be i.i.d. random variables that are uniformly integrable with respect to some probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. I wonder under what condition(s) the random variables $X_{n}\mathbb{I}(X_{1} > M)$ can be made small uniformly in $n$ by choosing $M$; specifically, I wonder when it can be done that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there are some $M > 0$ and some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{n}\mathbb{I}(X_{1} > M) < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Since they're independent, $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\mathbb{I}(X_{1} > M) > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon) \mathbb{P}(X_1 > M)$, and unless the $X_i$ are bounded, you will never get either factor to be zero.

Comment: What? You are saying that $X_n$ and $I_{X_n >M}$ are independent?

Comment: Maybe, you are interested $\mathbb E[X_{n}\mathbb{I}(X_{1} > M)] < \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no chance for that to happen. Take $X_n$ i.i.d. with standard normal distribution.